# Nested association query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
Class User
  has_many :universities
end

Class University
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :courses
end

Class Course
  belongs_to :university
end
```

Now, I want to find the `courses` of any user.

I can use the following query:

```
User.find(1).universities.collect{|x| x.courses}
```

But is there any other simple ways to get this result? Please explain your answer so that I can understand. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: First a question. Are you expecting to get all available courses at all universities that the user has?

Comment: yes, You're right. @Coenwulf

Answer (score 3):

Add into `User` model:

```
has_many :courses, through: :universities
```

Now you can fetch all courses of a user via:

```
User.find(1).courses
```

From docs (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association):

> A has_many :through association is often used to set up a many-to-many connection with another model. This association indicates that the declaring model can be matched with zero or more instances of another model by proceeding through a third model.